# Centering JPanel with GridBoxLayout is repeatedly adding the JPanel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel, center

After doing a whole lot of research, I can't seem to find anything with my problem. I'm creating a program where a user selects the tab (JTabbedPane) they'd like to use. Within that tab, I have a JPanel that I add to the tab when the user selects the tab.

```
private void tabEventsStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                       
    if (tabEvents.getSelectedComponent().equals(tabAddEvent)) {
        JPanel jp = new AddEvent();
        tabAddEvent.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        tabAddEvent.add(jp);
        tabAddEvent.updateUI();
    }
    else if (tabEvents.getSelectedComponent().equals(tabEditEvent)) {
        JPanel jp = new EditEvent();
        tabEditEvent.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        tabEditEvent.add(jp);
        tabEditEvent.updateUI();
    }
else if (tabEvents.getSelectedComponent().equals(tabDeleteEvent)) {
        JPanel jp = new DeleteEvent();
        tabDeleteEvent.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        tabDeleteEvent.add(jp);
        tabDeleteEvent.updateUI();
    }
else {
    System.out.println("Error! Tab Not Selected!");
}
}
```

The JPanels center perfectly. However, I was frustrated to find that when I click on tabEditEvent(or tabDeleteEvent) after tabAddEvent and then back to tabAddEvent, the JPanel gets added again. This creates a weird UI where I have 2 identical forms sitting side by side and no longer in the center... Same goes with tabEditEvent and tabDeleteEvent. If I clicked on any tab 3 times, I'll have 3 JPanels added to the container, and so on...

**Update**

This was one part of the original code from my friend's programme:

```
else if (tabEvents.getSelectedComponent().equals(tabEditEvent)) {
        JPanel jp = new EditEvent();
        tabEditEvent.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        tabEditEvent.add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        tabEditEvent.updateUI();
    }
```

**Update 2**

In a desperate attempt to solve this, I've taken screenshots of the result so that you can see what I'm trying to describe.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/isj5iezwcak1bfn/Untitled-1.png

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rywe1e5hgx7c88x/Untitled-2.png

I tried looking into CardLayout and unfortunately, I can't wrap my head around it

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what your doing. Normally, you would create the different panels ahead of time, and then add each panel as it's own tab on the tabbedPane. This would all be done before the GUI is even shown.  It sounds like you're re-inventing the wheel by dynamically creating content as the user clicks a tab. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have already created the different panels. In the sample code, I have 3 different panels, each with it's own forms and codes (AddEvent(), EditEvent() and DeleteEvent()). This sample code is in turn in another file (JFrame) that has a JTabbedPane (tabEvents).

What I'm trying to do now is to display those individual panels in the JTabbedPane for the user.

Comment: For better help sooner, please post a [Minimal Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem, not just a code snippet.

Comment: This is the only code within the file though. I'm not sure how else to demonstrate the problem. This is actually code copied from a friend's programme. He used BorderLayout instead, but that didn't center the panels

Comment: I updated with the BorderLayout snippet. I really don't know how else to display the different panels in another container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helped out and told me to use a boolean if statement to find out if I had already added the panel

```
if (tabEvents.getSelectedComponent().equals(tabAddEvent)) {
        JPanel jp = new AddEvent();
    if (initializedAdd == false) {
    tabAddEvent.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    tabAddEvent.add(jp);
    initializedAdd = true;
    }
    }
```

Worked nicely! Once this project is done, I shall be looking closer into all the Layouts though!

Thanks to everyone for trying to help.

Answer (score 2):

- [don't to use updateUI()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html#updateUI()) ---> code line `tabDeleteEvent.updateUI();`

.

```
public void updateUI()
Resets the UI property with a value from the current look and feel.
Overrides:
updateUI in class JComponent
See Also:
JComponent.updateUI()
```

---

1. use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead of add/remove `JComponents`
2. call code lines `tabDeleteEvent.revalidate();` and `tabDeleteEvent.repaint();` after all changes to already visible Swing GUI are done in the case that you have to add/remove `JComponents` repeatly

Comment: Revalidate and repaint didn't work. I'm not too keen on learning to use CardLayout atm as I'm kinda in a hurry to finish this =/

Comment: Invoking `updateUI()` in this context is wholly inappropriate. Without change, the interest on this [debt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) will continue to accrue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason its repeating is your adding new panels each time. Add the panels to the constructor for the class and then just navigate between the tabs in the code you have above.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by navigate?